# Google Apps Script trigger email notification with onEdit when cell contents changes from function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to modify this script and it works when I manually change the contents of anything in A, but I would like the script to trigger when the contents of the cells in A change from what they were before from a formula I have (importXML) that's pulling data in from another site. It's just a single sheet and just the one importxml function.

```
    function sendNotification() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
      var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
      var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
      var recipients = "@gmail.com";
      var message = '';
      if(cell.indexOf('A')!=-1){ 
        message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();
      }
      var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
      var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For    message: «' + message + '»';
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your triggering function is 'sendNotification',

```
function sendNotification(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var recipients = "reciever@gmail.com";
  var message = '';
  var range = event.range;
  if ( (range.getColumn() == 1) && (event.value != event.oldValue)) {
    message = event.value;
    var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
    var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + range.getRow() + '». New comment: «' + event.value + '». For    message: «' + message + '»';
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
}
```

Plus you might need to manually configure the trigger,

- Select Resources -> Current project's triggers. -> Click link to add
  one now.
- Under Run, select the function you want executed by the trigger. (In
  your case "sendNotification(e)")
- Under Events, select From Spreadsheet.
- From the next drop-down list, select On On edit.
- Click Save.

Enjoy

Comment: Hmm I don't think this is working, or I can't get it to work yet. When I try to run manually I get "e is not defined" and when I try to test in my sheet, I don't get e-mail updates even if I manually make a change to something in column A. I changed "if(cell.indexOf('A')!=-1){ "  to "if (e.value() != e.oldValue()) {" in my above code

Comment: @cjduble My mistake it should be 'e.value' and 'e.oldValue'. I edited the answer

Comment: Still no dice -- http://imgur.com/a/gJvwn is what I currently get, again I tried running manually and also putting in edits manually into my sheet. I really do appreciate the help here :)

Comment: Check your function again, 'sendNotification(e)'. you have missed 'e' parameter.

Comment: I have edited the code. I checked it and works fine.

Comment: Heh thank you, still no dice, on a manual run I get "TypeError: Cannot read property "value" from undefined. (line 9, file "onEdit")" and when I run in the spreadsheet still no dice from manual changes in the spreadsheet

Comment: use my code posted above and manually configure the trigger as I mentioned. comment other onEdit functions and check. it works fine with me

Comment: Hey there, with your code the e-mail does trigger, but still only for manual changes to my sheet. I want the e-mail to trigger whenever the contents of the sheet/cell changes from my importXML function....any ideas? Or can onEdit not pick that up?